# Issue when using Vagrant+Puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I'm using Vagrant and I'm trying to use Puppet as a tool for provisioning one of my virtual machines.
I created a folder named 'manifests' in the same directory of my Vagrantfile. Inside the 'manifests' folder I created a file named db.pp with the following content:

```
exec { "apt-update":
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
}
package { "mysql-server":
  ensure  => installed,
  require => Exec["apt-update"],
}
```

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.define :db do |db_config|
    db_config.vm.network :private_network, :ip => "192.168.33.10"
    db_config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
      puppet.manifest_file = "db.pp"
    end
  end
end
```

But when I type `vagrant up db` on command line, I receive the following error message: `The configured puppet manifest is missing. Please specify a path to an existing manifest`. Does anyone know what it is? My OS is Windows 7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it still didn't work.

Comment: How about renaming db.pp to default.pp and skipping the `manifest_file` option?

Comment: Guys, it worked!
The problem was that I was saving the file db.pp as a .txt file. Shame on me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To use the puppet provisioner you need to specify the following:

- manifest_file
- manifests_path

In your case looks like `manifest_file` is `db.pp`, and `manifests_path` is `manifests`

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = 2
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.define :db do |db_config|
    db_config.vm.network :private_network, :ip => "192.168.33.10"
    db_config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
      puppet.manifest_file = "db.pp"
      puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    end
  end
end
```

[Check the vagrant puppet provisioner page](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html)